# User Login with Firebase-Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with a simple login app using `firebase-realtime database`. What i want for the user is to login one-time only. So next time if user is previously logged in then user should be directed to home screen and not to login page.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `MainActivity` is your launcher activity (where the user will be landed when not logged in i.e it will be the login activity) and `ActivityHome` is the home activity that you want the user to redirect when they are logged in.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
                    // user is logged in, redirect to ActivityHome
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityHome.class));
                }
            }
        };  
    }
}
```

Now if the user is logged in, he/she will be redirected to ActivityHome, but if he is not logged in, he will stay on the MainActivity (the login activity).

Comment: Suppose I am having Google as well as Facebook login on a single activity then how it will work..?

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderId()
```

should return "firebase" , if no - than user not log in with firebase.

or better

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

check or null

Comment: Suppose I am having Google as well as Facebook login on a single activity then how it will work..?